# Prove Sn of $Ur ={1/n!} - {2/(n+1)!} +{ 1/(n+2)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$Ur ={1/r!} - {2/(r+1)!} +{ 1/(r+2)!}$
Prove that
$\sum_{r=1}^n  Ur= {1/2} - {  (n+1)/ (n+2)! }$

Comment: Please be more aware of typos.  In your definition of $U_r$, the right hand side contains $n$'s, and not $r$'s.  Surely you mean for it to be $U_r=\frac{1}{r!}-\frac{2}{(r+1)!}+\frac{1}{(r+2)!}$.  What have you tried?  Induction seems like a good idea.  Telescoping series also seems like it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more generally,
if
$u_r
=v_r-2v_{r+1}+v_{r+2}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{r=1}^n u_r
&=\sum_{r=1}^n (v_r-2v_{r+1}+v_{r+2})\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n v_r-2\sum_{r=1}^nv_{r+1}+\sum_{r=1}^nv_{r+2}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n v_r-2\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}v_{r}+\sum_{r=3}^{n+2}v_{r}\\
&=v_1+v_2+\sum_{r=3}^n v_r-2(v_2+v_{n+1}+\sum_{r=3}^{n}v_{r})+\sum_{r=3}^{n}v_{r}+v_{n+1}+v_{n+2}\\
&=v_1-v_2-v_{n+1}+v_{n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

If
$v_r = \frac1{r!}$,
this gives
$\sum_{r=1}^n u_r
=\frac1{1}-\frac1{2}
-\frac1{(n+1)!}
+\frac1{(n+2)!}
=\frac1{2}
+\frac{1-(n+2)}{(n+2)!}
=\frac1{2}
-\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}
$.

This generalizes to
$u_r
=\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k}v_{r+k}
$.
This is the case
$m=2$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other  method that not defining Vr

Comment: You might use $u_r = ((r+1)(r+2)-2(r+1)+1)/(r+2)!=(r^2+r+1)/(r+2)!$ but seems harder.

Comment: can u plz show how to do in that way